# Alter type Integer to Enum in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, enums, casting

I have a column called "abc_integer" which holds value of a foriegn key of a table which is only 2 values (1, 2). So I want to drop this column and add a new column "abc_enum" 
Note : I am trying this in Postgres 9.3 version

```
CREATE TYPE abc_enum_type ENUM AS ('hi', 'hello');
ALTER TABLE abc ADD COLUMN abc_enum abc_enum_type ;
UPDATE abc SET abc_enum = CASE 
           WHEN abc_integer == 1 THEN 'hi'::abc_enum_type
           ELSE 'hello'::abc_enum_type END ;
ALTER TABLE abc DROP COLUMN abc_intger;
```

Is there a better way doing this ?
Like accommodating all of these in a single statement Alter type and rename with USING clause ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can "compress" it by one step with `USING`, like:

```
alter table abc alter COLUMN abc_integer set data type abc_enum_type using case when abc_integer == 1 THEN 'hi'::abc_enum_type ELSE 'hello'::abc_enum_type END;
```

and then renaming the column `abc_integer` to `abc_enum`.

If that what you want [it works on 9.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-altertable.html)

Btw! Mind default values.

**Edit**
The way you do it does not lock the table. While altering column type will!

Comment: Thanks !! I don't have any default values .

Comment: Is both the above mentioned same ? Both will take same time to execute? Because for one we are changing type , on other hand we are updating for new column .

Comment: yeah. forgot to mention :)

Comment: Is there a way to accommodate the default value too?